# Execute function when press button, not click

Tags: c#, winforms

I need execute a function immediately before when I press button. Note, in the normal command `Button1_Click`, the function only executes after I release it. If I hold the button press, the function doesn't work, only before I release it.

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
    myFunction(); 
 }
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to ask. Please include sample code of the function, describe what it's currently doing, and clearly describe exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: I need to perform a function exactly when I press the button. By the common function Botao1_Click it only executes when you release the click; that is, if you click and hold a short time pressed it does not execute. If you hold down for 2 seconds, the function tb does not execute; It's only called after you release the ...

Comment: What do you even mean by "press button"? Pressing is clicking. Do you mean on the mouse down event? That's not related to naudio in any way

Comment: @mrsoliver I suspect you should start with a Windows Forms tutorial. Mouse events are fundamental in any kind of desktop programming

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "on mouse down". In the web world, there are 3 main mouse events: mousedown, mouseup, and click.

Answer (score 0):

you can use button KeyDown event for this functionality

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot... It's mouseDown event that i need... but i found when search for your tip.... So Mouse Down Event solved the question....